# Is there a way to send all the web traffic through a proxy without using ddwrt in an Asus router?

Tags: networking, router, proxy

Im about to buy an Asus RT-N10U B router. I need to know whether I can use it to pass all the traffic through my proxy server without flashing ddwrt into it?

Answer (score -1):

transparent application settingj tor proxy server. settings route. all through. tor transparent localhost  :9040
dns tor localhost:5400
socks localhost:9050
http gopher localhost:8118
or eg  router may have a proxy. or vpn pass through  ::24, 192.x.x.x: port no.

Comment: so TOR or VPN.. I guess any VPN software but can you state what VPN software you had in mind?

Comment: i use hotspot. sheild vpn it free version all platforms 2 gig allowance but i use on android after allowence it gives notification jus X it and carry on unblocks all sites and content. iv dl off torrents of 40 gig in less then my supposedly. 1 gig. allowence it still allows. tethering without restrictions tho topup 10 quid duz giv me unlimted browsing they try block streaming /downloads an vpn app bypasses fair usage :d 10 quid payg =unlimted. data for eva. an unlimited. txt all networks. :p

Comment: an. still get 10 credit the data m txt is just for topping up

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question whether you want all Internet traffic or just all http traffic,  but if you just want http, you can configure your browser settings to use a proxy for all of its requests.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, pauly, but I really wish you'd use better punctuation to make it more readable.  Cheers.